# Monitoring solution for Google Cloud (grafana/prometheus)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Client need monitoring solution and looking for grafana. Also want to explore prometheus. Here are some query

1. How to send all required metrics from Google cloud monitoring to prometheus ex compute engine,bigquery,storage,cloud run etc.
2. As End result will be on grafana then is it good to use direct grafana with GCP integration and removing prometheus out of picture.

Do not see enough documentation on how to send monitoring metrics and logs to prometheus

Answer (score 0):

To send metrics from GCP services to Prometheus for monitoring and visualizing in Grafana,you should install Prometheus and Grafana. Make sure that it is configured to listen on a public IP address or accessible via a load balancer.

Install the corresponding exporters for GCP services such as `stackdriver\_exporter`, `kube\_state\_metrics`,  `gce\_instance\_exporter`, etc., based on your requirements. These exporters will gather metrics from GCP APIs and expose them as Prometheus metrics.

Grant the necessary roles and permissions to allow the exporters to fetch metrics from GCP services. Configure Prometheus to scrape exporters by updating the **prometheus.yaml** and make sure that the exporters are reachable from the Prometheus server.

Now, you can import Prometheus data sources into Grafana and create a dashboard to visualize the desired metrics.

Here are some resources that might be useful for you:

[Get started with Grafana and Prometheus](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/getting-started/get-started-grafana-prometheus/)

[How to install and configure Prometheus and Grafana on Ubuntu](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-install-prometheus-and-grafana-on-ubuntu/)

[Google Cloud managed service for Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus)